# Update LibreOffice 4.2.4 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty

Tags: updates, libreoffice

LibreOffice have update into minor release 4.2.4. How to update them? I have seen the package list in Launchpad at LibreOffice PPA, but it's still not available until now (still 4.2.3 rc3).

Answer (score 1):

You are left with only one option: **manual install**

1. Remove LibreOffice: `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice*`
2. Download LibreOffice `deb` [amd64](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86_64&version=4.2&lang=en-US) or [i386](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86&version=4.2&lang=en-US).
3. Unarchive by right-clicking and choose `Extract Here`
4. Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
5. `cd` to the download directory, then `cd ./LibreOffice*` and `cd ./DEBS`
6. Install: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`